# What time requirement and certification does one need to become a Krav Maga instructor?

Tags: krav-maga, certification

How does one become a Krav Maga instructor in the United States?

More precisely:

- Is there a federal authority who fix the necessary requirement for teach as instructor?
- If there is one, what is the minimum belt needed for become an instructor?
- If there is, what is the minimum time that you have to train in Krav Maga before become an instructor?

Comment: Roughly the same way you become an instructor in any other system: keep studying until you are given partial responsibility for the training of others and accumulate enough experience in that task to be ready to handle students on your own, no?

Comment: Yes, but what level is needed ? Do you need a black belt for start to be an instructor or can you instruct with only brown belt ? Can you be an instructor in 3 years ?

Comment: I actually think its pretty quick, its not quite like a normal martial art.  The core basics are very very simple and I think the idea is you can teach these to people very quickly so they develop some useful skills in very little time.   It's not meant to be fully comprehensive with lots of techniques.  So the basic instructor is not to be confused with being a "black belt" in other arts.

Comment: Why -1 ? Can you be brave enough for explain it please ?

Comment: @BillyTheWind I didn't downvote, but I imagine because (a) lack of specificity, (b) trivially answerable by talking to someone involved in whatever KM association you're asking about, and (c) ultimately it's obvious--"get good, get certified".

Comment: @DaveNewton thank you for your comment. For a: do you said there is a lack of specificity because I didn't specified any country ? Well I was expected they may have some common directive from the country of origin. But I agree about this so I add US to the question. For b: I'm not agree about this. Yes I can ask to my instructor but I would like a general objective reply. For c: I'm not agree with this objection because what is asked here is some precision.

Comment: @BillyTheWind (a) No, country has little to do with it, ranking and instructorship has to do with the association. (b) There is only association-specific replies, and to get that, you should be talking to the association, because *they're the ones that confer instructorship*--this should be obvious. (c) That *is* the "general, objective" reply, because how to go about doing that depends on the association.

Comment: @DaveNewton please can you explaine what do you mean by association ? Who/What is it ?

Comment: @BillyTheWind It's the "governing body" of a KM school; essentially all KM schools are part of a KM association. (Many, many other martial arts schools are as well.) The association determines how one becomes an instructor that represents that association. Only each association can give you specifics on how to become an instructor for that association.

Comment: @DaveNewton for come back on the point abc. About a) it's depend of the country, some country have more legislation on harmonization about sportive activity. b) You said obvious. Well, obvious if your are use to  martial art . Some activity have very specific and harmonized chart for the requirement needed to be instructor. c) I didn't expected that there is so many different association with different requirement. That not make sens for me that every association can give a different answer since it's the same activity.

Comment: @BillyTheWind Whether or not you think it makes sense doesn't matter to the associations: each determines how they confer rank and status. They may do it the same, they may do it different, but they're the ones who make the rules they follow, and they're the ones best equipped to explain those rules to you.

Comment: @BillyTheWind Also, any given style is likely to have only one or possibly a few associations. They exist so there *is* a common, unified source of answers to questions like this. Otherwise anybody could go around calling themselves a teacher of style XYX. You may not *like* that this is how things have gone, but in general, it is. There are also plenty of unaffiliated schools (my gong fu school, for example) but a ranking or belt conferred by an unaffiliated school will carry little weight outside of that school.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I am an official licensee of Krav Maga Worldwide, a sanctioned organization of krav maga. I own and operate two schools in my area & have been teaching for close to 10 years, but I am not a black belt in krav maga. I am what they rank as Expert III/IV in black belt preparation and will have up to 2 more years before qualifying to test for black belt.

When I began, I was already a higher level student & entered what we call Phase training in LA, at their nat. training headquarters. This consists of 7 days of physical, mental, and teaching type of training with a final phase testing. Having previous krav maga training, I went through the program at an accelerated pace but still had to do each phase & then enter Expert & do each of them passing each test.

As far as your question, you can definitely become an instructor in krav maga in three years, but you will not be a black belt nor the nor the best instructor you can be. On average, it takes 5 to 7 years to test for a black belt in krav maga (by US standards as opposed to Israeli standards when I started my krav maga training in NYC).

Answer (score 3):

You become a certified instructor, which means passing an instructor's course supervised by a certified coach. Once you're an instructor you can grant belts up to blue if you're ranked two belts higher.

Instructor in three years? Sure. I'm leery of people who ask questions like that, though.

Comment: Did you try to discredit me ? What are you leery of ? Can you explain your said ?

Comment: @BillyTheWind "Did I try to discredit you?" I'm not sure what you mean. I believe that people that ask questions like "Can I do X in Y time" have motivations outside of what I prefer to deal with. Learning an art shouldn't be about time compression. For example, if I ran a dojo and someone asked me a question like that, I'd answer truthfully, but suggest they might be happier somewhere else.

Comment: ok thanks for this explanation, no problem so. Just a precision, KM is not strictly speaking an art. You advance an interesting information in your reply about the belt. Do you have any reference for it ?

Comment: @BillyTheWind http://www.israelikrav.com/index.php?option=com_content&view=article&id=46&Itemid=13, see the "belt or ranking system" question. Other KM orgs may do things differently.

Comment: Just a precision about what you write before, you let let think that I ask "can I be an instructor in 3 year". As an example, I wrote "Can you be an instructor in 3 years ?". Maybe I'm not interested at all by be an instructor, I'm just curious about the formation of the Krav Maga instructor ...

Answer (score 1):

Well, if you're going to believe a website called [kravmaga.com](http://www.kravmaga.com/programs/law-enforcement-military/instructor-certification/), there are instructor certification programs. I linked you to one under "law enforcement / military".

It seems to be very much documented and regimented.

[Edit - or check out [krav-maga.com](http://krav-maga.com/exclusive-krav-maga-training) - these give you more information on prerequisites.]

Either way, in the end, you'll probably just end up with a piece of paper that says you can teach Krav Maga.

Comment: Just have a quick look but didn't find necessary requirements. They said to call for more information.

Comment: Would you like me to call them up?

Comment: nice irony. There is several reason why I don't want to call. One of them is that the owner of the website have a commercial interest in the certification of the instructor. Just look at the price section who is very well documented. I would prefer something more unbiased from another source.

Comment: I doubt you'll find that, to be honest.